# java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble function in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

I have a BinaryStream class in JavasScipt that reads bytes from an array downloaded via XMLHHttpRequest and has the function next() which returns an unsigned byte (technically an integer). I need to read a double from the stream which is basically the same as [DataStream.readDouble()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readDouble%28%29) from Java which uses the method [Double.longBitsToDouble(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29). I can't figure out how the longBitsToDouble method works.

This is the the code I have:

```
var bits = stream.nextLong();
if (bits == 0x7ff0000000000000)
    this.variables = [Infinity];
else if (bits == 0xfff0000000000000)
    this.variables = [-Infinity];
else if (bits >= 0x7ff0000000000001 && bits <= 0x7fffffffffffffff || bits >= 0xfff0000000000001 && bits <= 0xfff0000000000001)
this.variables = [NaN];
else
{
    var s = ((bits >> 63) == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    var e = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7ff);
    this.variables = [(e == 0) ? (bits & 0xfffffffffffff) << 1 : (bits & 0xfffffffffffff) | 0x10000000000000];
    // This must be incorrect because it returns a number many times higher than it should
}
console.log(this.variables[0]);
```

Comment: JavaScript bitwise operators cannot operate on numbers which are greater than `0x7ffffff` (2,147,483,647). `0x80000000 >> 0` gives `-2147483647`, instead of `2147483648`.

Comment: Ah, that's a major problem. You don't happen to have a workaround do you?

Comment: Thanks, that may be all I need.

Comment: So, do you need a method to *just* perform bitwise operations? Can you post a comment with examples of your code, eg input + expected output?

Comment: I need a function that can turn an array of eight bytes into an IEEE 754 float e.g. turn [64, 103, 224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] into 191, which is the same as the DataStream.readDouble() method in Java.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that all the numbers are the same type. Ignore the code for I copied it from the Double.longBitsToDouble() Javadoc and I don't really know what it is supposed to do. I updated the post with the code that writes the float.

Comment: That's certainly NOT JavaScript. Are you sure that you're trying to code a JavaScript application? **[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) is very different from [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)**

Comment: It is not JavaScript, it is smalltalk from a desktop application. I am attempting to make an online app that can open the file made with the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a JavaScript library that can encode and decode many different types of numbers from an array of bytes [here](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser).

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/corp/compatibility/Numbers.java has an implementation of `floatToLongBits`.  I'd start with that.  You should be able to just tweak the mantissa mask and size and the exponent mask and size.

Joel Webber (of GWT [advises caution](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/72fc60b10f603869?fwc=1)):

> The Quake code has only ever been tested on WebKit (Nitro & V8), so I would 
>   check it carefully before using. `float`/`doubleToLongBits()` in Javascript is a 
>   truly, truly foul piece of work that is horrifically inefficient. Use with 
>   caution.